# Need help to understand the status of domain

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, domain-registrar, domain-transfer

Hi guys may be some one can help me to understand that DNS record:

```
Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC
Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com
Name Server: NS1.SEDOPARKING.COM
Name Server: NS2.SEDOPARKING.COM
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientRenewProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 30-aug-2013
Creation Date: 15-aug-2002
Expiration Date: 15-aug-2014
```

- Does that mean that the domain will be expired soon?
- Why that domain has 5 statuses?
- Does that statuses means that domain owner cant control the domain state?

Comment: If you have a look at the name servers in this _WHOIS_ record, you'll see the domain is parked with Sedo, a domain marketplace - see [here](http://www.sedo.com/us/park-domains/producttour/parking-your-domains/). It's unlikely given the creation date, renewal fees invested, and interest in selling it...that they'll just let it expire. You can try to purchase it through Sedo if you're really interested in it. Otherwise there's lots of new gTLD's now that might work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any registered domain is registered for a period of time. As this period begins to lapse, the domain owner can renew the domain name or let it lapse which allows the domain name to be re-registered after a period of time to allow the owner to reclaim the domain name.

The various statuses indicate the the domain name owner has locked the record. This is a security option that prevents the domain from being transferred, modified, deleted, and so on. The domain name owner retains the control of the domain name, but the registrar is the agent through which the domain is registered and a business arrangement exists.

In this case, the domain was registered in 2002 and expires in 2014 which means that the domain name has been renewed at least once and likely renewed several times. If you want this domain name, it is likely that the domain name will continue to be renewed. However, with GoDaddy and other registrars, there are options to be notified when this domain name becomes available for registration. If the domain name is wanted by more than one person, there may be a bidding process or an order in which people can either register the domain name or pass.